# How to call notebook or run jobs from C# in databricks using Mobius?

Tags: c#, azure-hdinsight, azure-databricks, mobius

I'm new to Databricks.Is it possible to send the code passing through API (like Mobius) from C# to run jobs in Databricks ?

Could you possibly give me some code example ? 
such as if I want to run some job in notebook which contain the NoSql code in there.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the jobs api https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/jobs.html. Either the create job call or runnow depending on what you want to do.